# Get the direction an object's axis is pointing in Maya

Tags: python, orientation, axis, maya

Using python I'm trying to confirm that a given transform node in Maya has it's Y axis pointing up, Z axis pointing forward, and X axis pointing to the side, like in the picture below. The transform node might be a child to another transform node in a hierarchy of unknown depth.

My first thought was to use xform rotate pivot matrix? I'm not sure if this is the correct thing or how to interpret the matrix values.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most objects, you can get the orientation in world space quite simply:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

world_mat = cmds.xform(my_object, q=True, m=True, ws=True)
x_axis = world_mat[0:3]
y_axis = world_mat[4:7]
z_axis = world_mat[8:11]
```

If you want them in vector form (so you can normalize them or dot them) you can use the maya api to get them as vectors.  So for example

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.api.OpenMaya as api

my_object = 'pCube1'
world_mat = cmds.xform(my_object, q=True, m=True, ws=True)
x_axis = api.MVector(world_mat[0:3])
y_axis = api.MVector(world_mat[4:7])
z_axis = api.MVector(world_mat[8:11])

# 1 = straight up, 0 = 90 degrees from up, -1 = straight down
y_up = y_axis * api.MVector(0,1,0)
```

This will include the any modifications that might have been made to the `.rotateAxis` parameter on the object so it's not guaranteed to line up with the visual tripod if that's been manipulated.

If you don't have reason to expect the `.rotateAxis` has been set, this the easiest way to do it.   A good intermediate step would be just to warn on objects that have a non-zero `.rotateAxis` so there is no ambiguity in the results, it might be unclear what the correct course of action there is in any case.

Comment: So simple, and it works. I spent hours trying various solutions and this was the only one that produced the correct vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped @theodox answer into a function. Maybe it will be helpful to someone in the future.

```
def getOrientation(obj, returnType='point'):
    '''
    Get an objects orientation.

    args:
        obj (str)(obj) = The object to get the orientation of.
        returnType (str) = The desired returned value type. (valid: 'point', 'vector')(default: 'point')

    returns:
        (tuple)
    '''
    obj = pm.ls(obj)[0]

    world_matrix = pm.xform(obj, q=True, m=True, ws=True)
    rAxis = pm.getAttr(obj.rotateAxis)
    if any((rAxis[0], rAxis[1], rAxis[2])):
        print('# Warning: {} has a modified .rotateAxis of {} which is included in the result. #'.format(obj, rAxis))

    if returnType is 'vector':
        from maya.api.OpenMaya import MVector

        result = (
            MVector(world_matrix[0:3]),
            MVector(world_matrix[4:7]),
            MVector(world_matrix[8:11])
        )

    else:
        result = (
            world_matrix[0:3],
            world_matrix[4:7],
            world_matrix[8:11]
        )


    return result
```